# How to animate my header as it changes?

Tags: angular

I have this very generic layout for my app with a header on top and a content container below it:

```xml
<div class="main" [@applicationTransition]="applicationState" fxLayout="column" fxFlexFill>

  <nav class="header">
      <!-- insert header content & animate it -->
  </nav>

  <main class="content" fxLayout="column" fxFlex>
    <router-outlet #o="outlet" fxLayout="column" fxFlex></router-outlet>
  </main>

</div>
```

So, at this point I got my head around animations - or at least around the basics.

If I understood this correctly, then `:enter` and `:leave` are states where a component gets either added or removed from the DOM, right?

This is why I think it would be self-evident if I added a `headerTransition` which animates a changing header (e.g. on navigation events).

In my application I want each component to set the content of my header. Then I want to make use of the `:enter` and `:leave` states s.t. the default `headerTransition` gets executed.

So how could I realize that? Would I use a second  `<router-outlet>` for this or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a header with content dictated by the components rendered in the `router-outlet`, by following the advice presented by Alex Rickabaugh (angular core team) in this [presentation](https://youtu.be/rKbY1t39dHU?t=1m33s).

You have to create a custom structural directive. Full source code is available in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/adv-ng-left-nav).

Example usage:

**a.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  template: `
<h2>I am Route A</h2>

<div *topNav>
  <h3>Route A Nav</h3>
</div>
`
})
export class RouteA {}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
<top-nav></top-nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

For animations you should use `query` combined with `:enter` and `:leave` keywords. You can bind it to the `navId$` stream.

**app.component.html**

```
<nav [@enterLeave]="navId$ | async">
   // header content here
</nav>
```

**app.animations.ts**

```
trigger('enterLeave', [
  transition(':increment', [
    query(':leave', [
      animate('0.5s', style({
        opacity: 0
      })),
      style({
        display: 'none'
      })
    ]),
    query(':enter', animate('0.5s', style({
      opacity: 1
    }))),
  ]),
]);
```

**app.component.ts**

```
navId$: Observable <number>;

constructor(private router: Router) {
  this.navId$ = this.router.events.pipe(
    filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd),
    map(e => e.id),
  )
}
```

Comment: Hm. Either I am doing it wrong or this solution can't do more than changing text. The problem is that as I add icons or routerLinks nothing works as I am getting an `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` among other issues.